# Show/hide a KineticJS layer loaded from JSON within Angular

Tags: json, angularjs, canvas, kineticjs

I am trying to hide a layer in KineticJS that is built from a JSON string. The layer won't hide, however. If I try to hide a shape having an ID in the JSON, it does work. Not sure if I have incorrectly created my layer ID in the JSON, or if KineticJS has issues with layer showing/hiding. There is no console error. The layer just won't hide. KineticJS is version v5.1.1. Help?

Here's the relevant JSON....
 `{
    "attrs": {
        "width": 524,
        "height": 500
    },
    "className": "Stage",
    "children": [
        {
            "attrs": {},
            "className": "Layer",
            "id": "layer1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "attrs": {
                        "draggable": true
                    },
                    "className": "Group",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "attrs": {
                                "id": "firstShape",
                                "x": 25,
                                "y": 25,
                                "radius": 190,
                                "fill": "green"
                            },
                            "className": "Circle"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrs": {
                                "width": "auto",
                                "height": "auto",
                                "x": 64,
                                "y": 120,
                                "text": "Some label",
                                "fontSize": 10,
                                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                                "fill": "white"
                            },
                            "className": "Text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  }`

Here's the event handler which does the layer hide... I find that this is getting called correctly, and the layer just isn't hiding.

```
scope.$on('hideLayer', function(){
 scope.kineticStageObj.get('#layer1').hide();
 scope.kineticStageObj.draw();
});
```

Comment: Do you have any demo? This works fine: http://jsbin.com/feluna/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your json is wrong. `id` of layer should be inside `attrs` object.

```
"attrs": {
   "id: : "layer1"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
    "attrs": {
        "width": 524,
        "height": 500
    },
    "className": "Stage",
    "children": [
        {
            "attrs": {
                "id": "layer1"
            },
            "className": "Layer",           
            "children": [
                {
                    "attrs": {
                        "draggable": true
                    },
                    "className": "Group",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "attrs": {
                                "id": "firstShape",
                                "x": 25,
                                "y": 25,
                                "radius": 190,
                                "fill": "green"
                            },
                            "className": "Circle"
                        },
                        {
                            "attrs": {
                                "width": "auto",
                                "height": "auto",
                                "x": 64,
                                "y": 120,
                                "text": "Some label",
                                "fontSize": 10,
                                "fontFamily": "Arial",
                                "fill": "white"
                            },
                            "className": "Text"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```